# Gatsby site won't show on debian VPS

Tags: apache, deployment, debian, gatsby

I seem to encounter an issue deploying a Gatsby site to a debian 10 VPS.
My website is already online on a simple web hosting, and works well. Since I rent a VPS, I was looking forward to migrate my site from the web hosting to the VPS.

I tried, for a quick test, to just copy the content of the `public` folder in `var/www/html` but it rendered nothing (white page). If I just put a simple `index.html` with a "hello world", it works.

Today I tried to clone the project to `/home/user/mysite`, run `gatsby build` and then add a symlink to my `public` folder in `/var/www/html`.

Everything built fine, but it still shows a white page. Am I missing something ? I watched a Youtube video of a guy doing the exact same thing as me on a VPS and that worked. I'm not really an experienced linux user (hence the VPS, to learn), and I have no idea what to do.

**EDIT**:
you can see the repo [here](https://github.com/Sonicfury/theolambert.com)

Also console output seems to reveal a socket.io error

**EDIT 2**:
I reloaded (after an hour) the page with the symlink from the cloned repo and the site seems to load partially, it still fails to load some resources though.
However the copied public folder still shows nothing but the console output about socket.io.

Comment: What's the console output when you copy the full  `public` folder?

Comment: @FerranBuireu nothing fancy just the list of the files and then `[22/12/2020 12:54] Upload items completed in 20 s 124 ms: 12 folders created, 60 files transferred (130.6 kbit/s)`

Comment: I mean, there's no error in the browser's console but you still get a blank page?

Comment: oh, sorry misunderstood ! I have some socket.io error ```Échec du chargement pour l’élément <script> dont la source est « http://XX.XX.XX.XX/socket.io/socket.io.js ».``` indeed (sorry I don't know how to change output language to english), it means "Fail to load the <script> element which source is "server address/socket.io/socket.io.js".
But I did install socket.io manually on the VPS...

Comment: By the way, do you run `gatsby build`, don't you?

Comment: Yes, I run `gatsby build`